# Cannot boot into ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, windows-8, uefi, system-installation

Below given are the steps which I followed to install ubuntu 12.10 with existing windows 8 in my machine.

1. I downloaded ubuntu 12.10 into my disk and made it bootable from my usb by selecting that iso file.
2. Then restared my mahine and in BIOS I selected boot from usb.
3. Went into Linux os and selected install ubuntu alongside windows 8. It asked for memory allocation and I selected 550 GB for Ubuntu and 404GB for Windows. After that it completed ubuntu installation.
4. The booted into my windows 8 and used easyBCD to add a new entry.
   Ubuntu
   grup2
5. Now the easyBCD shows,

   ```
   There are a total of 4 entries listed in the bootloader.

   Default: Windows 8
   Timeout: 10 seconds
   EasyBCD Boot Device: C:\

   Entry #1
   Name: Lenovo Recovery System
   BCD ID: {e58d0cb6-2eae-11e2-9d20-806e6f6e6963}
   Device: \Device\HarddiskVolume3
   Bootloader Path: \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\LrsBootMgr.efi

   Entry #2
   Name: EFI USB Device
   BCD ID: {e58d0cb5-2eae-11e2-9d20-806e6f6e6963}
   Device: Unknown
   Bootloader Path: 

   Entry #3
   Name: Windows 8
   BCD ID: {current}
   Drive: C:\
   Bootloader Path: \windows\system32\winload.efi

   Entry #4
   Name: Ubuntu 12.10
   BCD ID: {6f173570-3bce-11e2-be74-c0143dd589c0}
   Drive: C:\
   Bootloader Path: \NST\AutoNeoGrub0.mbr
   ```
6. Next I restarted my system and in the boot options it shows windows 8 and ubuntu 12.10
7. When I click on ubuntu it displays,

   ```
   \NST\AutoNeoGrub0.mbr
   status 0xc000007b
   The application or operating system cold not be loaded because a required file is    missing or contains errors.
   ```
8. I am able to see C:\NST\AutoNeoGrub0.mbr Not sure why it shows file not present

Can you help me resolve this...

Thanks :)

Comment: In my machine, I am able to see C:\NST\AutoNeoGrub0.mbr Not sure why it shows file not present..

Comment: You've installed Ubuntu 12.10 but not GRUB boot-loader, and your system continued to boot directly into Windows where you then installed EasyBCD to dual-boot your system but it can only boot Windows and not Ubuntu, is that right?

If so, the problem seems to be arising from this Windows application, i.e. EasyBCD for which you might be able to get better support from them.

As an alternative, you might try installing and using GRUB boot-loader that comes with Ubuntu, which is proven to work perfectly and much better for dual-booting Ubuntu and Windows.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sadi. I tried as you told. But I got "Fatal error grub-install dummy" After this it simply gets stuck. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Sorry, apparently I've overlooked that you have Windows 8 and not 7, which I'm familiar with. It seems Windows 8 somehow prevents GRUB installation. In this case perhaps you might search for a solution to this problem by searching for something like "Ubuntu/Linux and Windows 8 dual-boot" which might display results showing how this monopolist/totalitarian Windows 8 nuisance can be overcome ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I installed Windows 8 alongside Ubuntu with no dual-boot problems.
In your case I would try this:

1. Boot into Live Ubuntu, using a USB pen or CD.
2. Open a terminal and type:
3. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`
4. If you are not secure of what you are doing, just press `Recommended repair` button.
5. If you know what you are doing click advanced options and configure the Grub installation as you will.